# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/assertj/core/api/MapAssert;

Tags: android-studio, assertj, android-assertj

When running unitTest on AndroidStudio (1.4), my below test fail as per title i.e. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/assertj/core/api/MapAssert;`

```
@Test
public void mapTest() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Key1", "Value1");
    map.put("Key2", "Value2");
    Assertions.assertThat(map).isNotNull();
}
```

When I run it from command line using gradlew command, it passed. I'm already pointing my Java to jdk1.8.0_66.jdk. Anyone knows why?

(p/s: I get the latest AndroidStudio 2.0 Preview 5, my test fails massively. So I decided to stay with the older version of Android Studio).

Trying to search for help and found this link https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/395. Apparently he also face the same issue on IDE. Any clue what's the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I would double check the classpath.
Use assertj core 1.7.1 - it's a version depending on java 6 whcih I'm sure is Android compatible.

Hope it helps